# Explicit dependency on a global service in a ngModule

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, module

I'm trying to understand something about modules.

I have an **AppModule** (my root module) that contains a **PageModule** and a **ServiceModule**. The **PageModule**  uses a service from **ServiceModule** (and future module will as well, but not the **AppModule** directly). I want that service to be a singleton, so I use the following code in the Service declaration:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

But I want my **PageModule** to explicitly depend on the **ServiceModule** so that future devs are aware that the **PageModule** has that dependency. Should I import the **ServiceModule** in **PageModule**, event though it basically does nothing? Should I import the **ServiceModule** in the root **AppModule**? Have I misunderstood something?

#### My understanding:

I should use `providedIn: 'root'` in the **ServiceModule** (unless the module I'm using it in is LazyLoaded) and import the **ServiceModule** directly in **PageModule** without need to import it in **AppModule**. Am I right?

I hope the question is not redundant. I have tried to see other questions and read articles about Angular's dependency injection and modules, yet I do not understand if what I want is a bad practice or not.

Answer (score 2):

you can define forRoot method in ServiceModule and provide another module description for  AppModule. In such way AppModule can import your service module and initialize it, then PageModule and any other modules can explicitly import ServiceModule. a good overview [link](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/).

//ServiceModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class ServiceModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ServiceModule,
      providers: [
        SingletoneService
      ]
    };
   }

   constructor(
     private singletoneService: SingletoneService,
   ) {
    this.singletoneService.init();
   }
}
```

//AppModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SvgDefinitionsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ServiceModule.forRoot(),

  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Isn't the equivalent of using `providedIn: root`, though?

Comment: @cbaillat if you no need setup your service in certain order you can use providedIn: root